# How to create different ports on a cell in jointjs?

Tags: jointjs

How can I create a model with different input and output ports.

For example:

Inputs ports - triangles

Output ports - circles

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Your requirement is also not clear. Spend some time to write a good question.

Comment: @SuvenduShekharGiri, what is not clear? I want to draw different shapes for input and output ports. I have not found examples for this. I hape posted my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured that out, if anyone interested

I am using `<path class="port-body"/>`

and setting different `d` paths when creating a new `cell`:

```
// ...
'.inPorts .port-shape': {
   d: pathForInputPort
},
'.outPorts .port-shape': {
  d: pathForOutputPort
}
// ...
```

`